# What does generate .less file?

Tags: css

I'm working on mdbootstrap 4. I imported all required files. Almost everything works fine except one little bug. When I inspect elements, I noticed that there is a new file is loaded in browser called `theme.less` in the following path:

`http://localhost/demo/wp-content/themes/bootstrap-basic/scripts/css/less/theme.less`

All my css files are stored in the folder `http://localhost/demo/wp-content/themes/bootstrap-basic/scripts/css/` and there is no `.less` files in all of the project.

The question is: What does generate .less file?

Comment: Typically, `.less` files aren't generated - they are *to* generated `CSS`. Read more about LESS [here](http://lesscss.org/). Without having an intimate knowledge of the theme base in question, it's not possible to answer your question. Your problem would be best addressed in [the official support channels](https://wordpress.org/support/theme/bootstrap-basic/) for that theme.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by changing the main mdb minified file to another one

```
wp_enqueue_script('mdb-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/scripts/js/mdb.min.js', array(), '4.3.1', true);
```

to this line

```
wp_enqueue_script('mdb-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/scripts/js/compiled.min.js', array(), '4.3.1', true);
```

I don't know how it works, but changing this line solve the problem